# Holt-Winters and Abnormal termination in LNSRCH

Tags: r, time-series, optimization, exponential-smoothing

I try to fit data with Holt-Winters function in R. Nevertheless, i am getting the following message:

```
ts1<-ts(data$nb_decl,frequency=53)
hw1<-HoltWinters(ts1)

Warning message:
In HoltWinters(ts1) :
  optimization difficulties: ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH
```

'data' counts 313 lines and if I just delete or change the last value (or add 314th value), the code works... Am I doing something wrong? or what is the problem with my data?

see bellow the data used:

```
data
    week year nb_decl
1     00 2006       0
2     01 2006       0
3     02 2006       0
4     03 2006       1
5     04 2006       0
6     05 2006       1
7     06 2006       0
8     07 2006       0
9     08 2006       0
10    09 2006       0
11    10 2006       1
12    11 2006       0
13    12 2006       2
14    13 2006       1
15    14 2006       1
16    15 2006       0
17    16 2006       2
18    17 2006       0
19    18 2006       1
20    19 2006       0
21    20 2006       0
22    21 2006       0
23    22 2006       0
24    23 2006       1
25    24 2006       0
26    25 2006       1
27    26 2006       1
28    27 2006       0
29    28 2006       1
30    29 2006       0
31    30 2006       0
32    31 2006       0
33    32 2006       0
34    33 2006       0
35    34 2006       1
36    35 2006       0
37    36 2006       1
38    37 2006       0
39    38 2006       0
40    39 2006       0
41    40 2006       1
42    41 2006       1
43    42 2006       0
44    43 2006       0
45    44 2006       0
46    45 2006       1
47    46 2006       3
48    47 2006       2
49    48 2006       4
50    49 2006       2
51    50 2006       1
52    51 2006       1
53    52 2006       0
54    01 2007       0
55    02 2007       1
56    03 2007       1
57    04 2007       1
58    05 2007       0
59    06 2007       2
60    07 2007       0
61    08 2007       1
62    09 2007       1
63    10 2007       1
64    11 2007       1
65    12 2007       1
66    13 2007       1
67    14 2007       1
68    15 2007       1
69    16 2007       1
70    17 2007       0
71    18 2007       0
72    19 2007       1
73    20 2007       0
74    21 2007       0
75    22 2007       3
76    23 2007       0
77    24 2007       0
78    25 2007       1
79    26 2007       0
80    27 2007       2
81    28 2007       0
82    29 2007       1
83    30 2007       0
84    31 2007       0
85    32 2007       1
86    33 2007       0
87    34 2007       2
88    35 2007       1
89    36 2007       1
90    37 2007       1
91    38 2007       1
92    39 2007       2
93    40 2007       0
94    41 2007       3
95    42 2007       0
96    43 2007       0
97    44 2007       0
98    45 2007       3
99    46 2007       0
100   47 2007       0
101   48 2007       0
102   49 2007       0
103   50 2007       1
104   51 2007       1
105   52 2007       0
106   53 2007       0
107   00 2008       1
108   01 2008       9
109   02 2008       0
110   03 2008       0
111   04 2008       1
112   05 2008       0
113   06 2008       0
114   07 2008       2
115   08 2008       0
116   09 2008       2
117   10 2008       2
118   11 2008       1
119   12 2008       0
120   13 2008       0
121   14 2008       3
122   15 2008       1
123   16 2008       0
124   17 2008       1
125   18 2008       2
126   19 2008       1
127   20 2008       1
128   21 2008       1
129   22 2008       1
130   23 2008       2
131   24 2008       1
132   25 2008       1
133   26 2008       0
134   27 2008       0
135   28 2008       3
136   29 2008       0
137   30 2008       4
138   31 2008       1
139   32 2008       0
140   33 2008       1
141   34 2008       1
142   35 2008       2
143   36 2008       0
144   37 2008       1
145   38 2008       0
146   39 2008       0
147   40 2008       1
148   41 2008       0
149   42 2008       2
150   43 2008       1
151   44 2008       0
152   45 2008       1
153   46 2008       2
154   47 2008       0
155   48 2008       3
156   49 2008       3
157   50 2008       2
158   51 2008       0
159   52 2008       0
160   00 2009       2
161   01 2009       3
162   02 2009       3
163   03 2009       2
164   04 2009       3
165   05 2009       1
166   06 2009       1
167   07 2009       1
168   08 2009       1
169   09 2009       2
170   10 2009       3
171   11 2009       1
172   12 2009       1
173   13 2009       2
174   14 2009       1
175   15 2009       2
176   16 2009       4
177   17 2009       0
178   18 2009       0
179   19 2009       3
180   20 2009       0
181   21 2009       2
182   22 2009       0
183   23 2009       0
184   24 2009       1
185   25 2009       1
186   26 2009       1
187   27 2009       1
188   28 2009       3
189   29 2009       0
190   30 2009       3
191   31 2009       4
192   32 2009       0
193   33 2009       1
194   34 2009       3
195   35 2009       0
196   36 2009       2
197   37 2009       1
198   38 2009       1
199   39 2009       1
200   40 2009       2
201   41 2009       0
202   42 2009       0
203   43 2009       1
204   44 2009       3
205   45 2009       2
206   46 2009       2
207   47 2009       1
208   48 2009       0
209   49 2009       2
210   50 2009       0
211   51 2009       0
212   52 2009       0
213   00 2010       1
214   01 2010       2
215   02 2010       3
216   03 2010       2
217   04 2010       1
218   05 2010       2
219   06 2010       0
220   07 2010       2
221   08 2010       0
222   09 2010       1
223   10 2010       1
224   11 2010       1
225   12 2010       1
226   13 2010       1
227   14 2010       0
228   15 2010       1
229   16 2010       0
230   17 2010       1
231   18 2010       1
232   19 2010       1
233   20 2010       2
234   21 2010       0
235   22 2010       2
236   23 2010       4
237   24 2010       3
238   25 2010       4
239   26 2010       1
240   27 2010       1
241   28 2010       1
242   29 2010       2
243   30 2010       2
244   31 2010       2
245   32 2010       0
246   33 2010       0
247   34 2010       2
248   35 2010       0
249   36 2010       1
250   37 2010       1
251   38 2010       1
252   39 2010       1
253   40 2010       2
254   41 2010       4
255   42 2010       2
256   43 2010       1
257   44 2010       3
258   45 2010       1
259   46 2010       0
260   47 2010       6
261   48 2010       1
262   49 2010       1
263   50 2010       1
264   51 2010       2
265   52 2010      11
266    0 2011       0
267    1 2011       3
268    2 2011       2
269    3 2011       0
270    4 2011       3
271    5 2011       0
272    6 2011       4
273    7 2011       2
274    8 2011       1
275    9 2011       1
276   10 2011       1
277   11 2011       2
278   12 2011       2
279   13 2011       3
280   14 2011       1
281   15 2011       5
282   16 2011       3
283   17 2011       3
284   18 2011       1
285   19 2011       2
286   20 2011       1
287   21 2011       3
288   22 2011       0
289   23 2011       2
290   24 2011       1
291   25 2011       2
292   26 2011       1
293   27 2011       2
294   28 2011       2
295   29 2011       2
296   30 2011       1
297   31 2011       0
298   32 2011       0
299   33 2011       2
300   34 2011       0
301   35 2011       2
302   36 2011       1
303   37 2011       1
304   38 2011       1
305   39 2011       3
306   40 2011       3
307   41 2011       2
308   42 2011       2
309   43 2011       1
310   44 2011       2
311   45 2011       1
312   46 2011       1
313   47 2011       0
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you ran into a bona fide singularity in the optimization. That can happen. What can we do about it?

I'd recommend looking into the `forecast` package. My first idea was to use `ets()`, but it turns out that `ets()` cannot handle frequencies above 24, so it won't work for your weekly data.

However, the error message very helpfully points us to the `stlf()` function, which performs an STL (season, trend, level) decomposition and subsequent ETS/smoothing or ARIMA modeling on the deseasonalized data.

```
model <- stlf(ts1)
plot(model)
```

[image: default]

As you see, `stfl()` (which by default fits an ETS model after STL decomposition) decided on a model with no trend and an additive error. If you *definitely* want a Holt-Winters-like forecast including trend, you can specify this as follows (look at `?ets` to understand the `etsmodel` parameter, and note that `stfl()` will dampen the trend if you don't explicitly tell it not to dampen it):

```
model <- stlf(ts1,etsmodel="AAN",damped=FALSE)
plot(model)
```

[image: Holt-Winters-like]

Answer (score 0):

ETS is applied on deseasonalized data. But I do not find that how to apply ARIMA on deseasonalized data using stlf. I think that there is no such option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arima with `stlm` from the forecast package in R with the following command:

```
stlm(x, method = "arima", robust = T)
```